# Pygame Import Error: cannot import name _camera

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using the camera.py file from the examples folder supplied with pygame.

Unfortunately, every time I try to run camera.py, it shows this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "camera.py", line 92, in <module>
    main()
  File "camera.py", line 87, in main
    pygame.camera.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygame/camera.py", line 42, in init
    from pygame import _camera
ImportError: cannot import name _camera
```

I'm assuming that this means _camera.py is missing, though I'm not too sure.
Any help?

Comment: Which OS/version are you using? How have you installed Pygame?

Comment: I'm using pygame for python 3.3.2, for Mac OS X 10.8.3 (which may be the problem, since this isn't officially supported.) I'll try reinstalling again.

Comment: That file should only have 3 imports, `import pygame`, 
`import pygame.camera`, `from pygame.locals import *` . Also make sure you match the bit-version of pygame with python. (Not your OS bit version)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `from pygame import examples.camera` in order to select *camera* from the *examples* subfolder within the pygame module.
**nevermind, misread the question.**

I would suggest making sure your pygame is up to date